# Add image to a cell in ListView

Tags: .net, visual-studio, listview

I want to add images to determinate cells in my ListView, but i can add it only to the first item, here is my code:

```
    lblData.Text = Now
    lblR1.Text = Rulliera1.Item(0).CodiceRulliera
    lblVassoioR1.Text = "VASSOIO : " & Rulliera1.Item(0).CodiceVassoio
    For Each row As clsTotemAnime In Rulliera1
        Dim itm As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem("")
        itm.SubItems.Add(row.anima.descrArticolo)
        itm.SubItems.Add(row.CodiceAnima)
        If row.NonLavorare Then
            itm.ImageIndex = 0
        Else
            itm.ImageIndex = 1
        End If
        LVR1.Items.Add(itm)
    Next
```

With `itm.ImageIndex = 0` i can add an image to the first element in my row, but i want to do something like : `itm.SubItems(x).ImageIndex = 1`

One more thing: how can i center the image in the cell?

Comment: Use a DataGridView instead.

Comment: @HansPassant well u was right, more simple to use, tanks

Answer (score 0):

Add LVS_EX_SUBITEMIMAGES extended style to your ListView.